# Java: Splitting .GIF image in BufferedImages Gives Malformed Images

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

So I have a very small piece of code, which takes a .gif image as input, and then it splits this .gif image into an array of BufferedImage. After that, it stores the images in the array on the disk. When I do this, the output images contain heavy white-pixel noise which isn't visible in the input .gif image.

Example of the input gif:

[image: Input gif]

Example of malformed output image (the 3rd frame in the gif):

[image: Malformed image]

The code I am using to split the gif is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        splitGif(new File("C:\\test.gif"));
}

public static void splitGif(File file) throws IOException {
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix("gif").next();     reader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)), false);
    for(int i = 0; i < reader.getNumImages(true); i++) {
        BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(i + ".png"));
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What for `new File(i + ".gif")`? Gif transparency being for what it is. Maybe pure white needs to be transformed to transparent RGBA.

Comment: @JoopEggen I don't think it's an issue with pure white, as the pixels shown in the malformed image should be a dark color as shown in the source gif.

Comment: A secundary gif could have transparent pixels where the color is unaltered.

Comment: @JoopEggen I'm not quite sure if I know what you mean. So what you are saying, is that on the places where I do not see any color (or just white), the color should be the same as that of the frame before it?

Comment: Sounds logical; keep the previous image, for y / for x if white setRGB previous one. Or better draw the new frame onto an image.getGrapics as gif

Comment: @JoopEggen Ahh thanks, I will try to make a construction that allows for such decoding. I'll attempt to implement this when I get home, and i'll let you know the result :)

Comment: You cannot just decode an arbitrary frame from a GIF, because GIF uses delta compression, storing only the difference from the previous frame. Each frame also has a "disposal" method, that affects whether the previous frame should be cleared before the the new one is painted, etc. So, worst case, you need to decode all frames up until the current to display it correctly. Not really a problem though, if you as is typical, decode all in a loop anyway.

Comment: @JoopEggen You were right, the transparent pixels expect the pixel from the previous frame to be there. Would you like the honor of writing the answer, so I can approve your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved it yourself, but for good order: every next frame is the accumulation of all prior frames filling up the transparent pixels in the current frame.

```
public static void splitGif(File file) throws IOException {
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix("gif").next();
    reader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)), false);
    BufferedImage outImage = null;
    Graphics2D g = null;    
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.getNumImages(true); i++) {
         BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
         if (g == null) {
             BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                     BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
             g = (Graphics2D) outImage.getGraphics();
         }
         g.drawImage(lastImage, 0, 0, null);
         ImageIO.write(outImage, "PNG", new File(i + ".png"));
     }
     if (g != null) {
         g.dispose();
     }
}
```

- `getGraphics==createGraphics` should be balanced be a `dispose` as documented.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was that when reading .gif files into java, then all pixels in a given frame that did not change color compared to their previous frame will be fully transparent. If you want to read a .gif and split it in an array of properly rendered BufferedImages, then you have to fill the transparent pixels of the current frame with the last non-transparent pixel of one of the previous frames.

Code:

```
public static void splitGif(File file) throws IOException {
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix("gif").next();
    reader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)), false);
    BufferedImage lastImage = reader.read(0);
    ImageIO.write(lastImage, "PNG", new File(0 + ".png"));

    for (int i = 1; i < reader.getNumImages(true); i++) {
        BufferedImage image = makeImageForIndex(reader, i, lastImage);
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(i + ".png"));
    }
}

private static BufferedImage makeImageForIndex(ImageReader reader, int index, BufferedImage lastImage) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = reader.read(index);
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

    if(lastImage != null) {
        newImage.getGraphics().drawImage(lastImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
    newImage.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    return newImage;
}
```